# AudioUnitSampleType deprecated on iOS8, my render callback is not working now

Tags: callback, ios8, core-audio

I have an app that throws samples in a render callback using AudioUnitSampleType. It's deprecated on iOS 8, and the sound is not working now. Previous iOS versions worked perfect. I can't find any documentation on how to replace AudioUnitSampleType.

The only info i got is the xcode warning ... "The concept of canonical formats is deprecated"

Please, help, can anyone put some light on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've the same issue. You can replace `AudioUnitSampleType` with `SInt32`. I guess you have declared `AudioStreamBasicDescription` too, so replace your declaration from `streamFormat.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical;` to `streamFormat.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;`

Hope it will help.

EDIT:

You can also use `typealias` to define `AudioUnitSampleType`

EDIT: You also may consider switching to [TheAmazingAudioEngine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/)

Comment: Actually this does not work, or at least the part in the first paragraph. Adding the kAudioFormatIsFloat is not correct and will give you noise rather than audio.

Comment: I fear it's not that easy, as it might also be Float32. In CoreAudioTypes.h is a comment: "These types are deprecated. Code performing signal processing should use concrete types (e.g. float, Float32, SInt16, SInt32). Format-agnostic code, instead of relying on the sizes of these types, should calculate the size of a sample from an AudioStreamBasicDescription's mBytesPerChannel, mChannelsPerFrame, and (mFlags & kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved). For interleaved formats, the size of a sample is mBytesPerFrame / mChannelsPerFrame. For non-interleaved formats, it is simply mBytesPerFrame."

Comment: True. I actually prefer using [TheAmazingAudioEngine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/). I recently refactor my application and successfully integrated TAAE.

Comment: So, as long as you pick one concrete type (int or float) and stick to it (i.e., make your render callbacks etc. aware of it) you should be OK?

Comment: `kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical ` was defined as `kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved | (kAudioUnitSampleFractionBits << kLinearPCMFormatFlagsSampleFractionShift);` using this still works